# JLayeredPane not showing my custom JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm having trouble getting my custom panel to show up using JLayeredPanel.  I'm currently trying to create a black rectangle on the first layer, and on the second layer, I have a custom JPanel which is a slideshow of images.  The slideshow will not display at all, it only works when I add it to the frame. Any thoughts?

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private Container pane;
    private JPanel emptySlideShow;
    private JLayeredPane layeredPane;

    public GUI(){
        this.setVisible(true);
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);



        //      //Set up the content pane
        //      pane = this.getContentPane(); //get the content pane to place components
        //      pane.setLayout(null); //use absolute positioning (using Insets)
        //      pane.setBackground(new Color(236, 236, 236)); //color the background
        //
        //      //Set up the main menu bar
        this.emptySlideShow = new JPanel();
        this.emptySlideShow.setBounds(0,0,(int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth(),250);
        this.emptySlideShow.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));    

        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setLayout(null);
        layeredPane.add(this.emptySlideShow,new Integer(0));

        ArrayList<Image> slides = new ArrayList<Image>();

        Image image1 = new ImageIcon("pictures/slide1.png").getImage();
        slides.add(image1);

        Image image2 = new ImageIcon("pictures/slide2.png").getImage();
        slides.add(image2);

        ArrayList<String> transitions = new ArrayList<String>();
        transitions.add("PanLR");
        transitions.add("FadeOut");


        this.add(new SlideShow(slides,transitions));
        layeredPane.add(new SlideShow(slides,transitions),new Integer(1));


        this.add(layeredPane);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A guess since we don't have all of the pertinent code -- but you need to specify a component's size and position when adding it to the JLayeredPane, and so perhaps you're not setting the SlideShow's size before adding it (it's position will by default be 0, 0).

Question though: Why are you trying to add a SlideShow JPanel to the GUI **twice**? Once to the JLayeredPane, and the other to the JFrame itself?

Answer (score 1):

Simple. You are adding the components (including JLayeredPane) to the frame AFTER you invoke

```
this.setVisible(true);
```

Move this line to the end of the constructor and you should be fine or if you really want to keep this line at the top, you should call revalidate() to update the JFrame and components.